# Merging all the commits centrally

Tags: git, git-merge, git-push

To simplify the situation suppose two users commit history is like

```
A -> B -> C     A -> B -> D  # and Repo at  A -> B
```

and both two user try to push at **same time**.  First user will get chance first and now repo is at

```
A -> B -> C
```

Now 2nd user must have to  pull again before pushing so he's now at

```
A -> B -> C -> D or A -> B -> D -> C
```

So this rises two questions first is how this Merge happens(on timestamps..!)? How git decides which commits comes first C or D. And second is why this merging thing Cant be performed at Remote or Central Repo.(assuming there is no merge conflicts) ?

I am thinking about using git for some other **synching** technique So  suppose there is N users trying to push something at the same time then each user will have to pull N-1 times before being able to push.

So assuming there is no merge conflicts is there a way to perform a merge centrally. Just to clarify that user is going to pull eventually but i just want to avoid that N-1 pulls.

Comment: how will central merging solve the N-1 pulls issue? Every user will still have to sync the repo to get changes made by other users

Comment: The concurrency issue which you imagine as being a major problem usually is a minor one in practice, if at all.  If someone beats you to a push, then you just have to pull merge/rebase and deal with it.

Comment: dont you think it can be a major issue in practice if 100 user trying to push at the same time and last 1 will have to pull 99 time before being able to push.? event git take a little amount of time to integrate a new push.

Comment: What is stored in the repo ? Is it a regular code project (and users are developpers who regularly have to pull/push their work) ? or do you use git for some other storage & sharing purpose ?

Comment: as i just commented on answer. it is for **some other storage & sharing purpose**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> each user will have to pull N-1 times before being able to push

They won't: each user will pull then try again to push. If another user has not pushed in the meantime, that one pull will succeed.
The chances to have to pull n-1 times (meaning each push fails because one other user has just pushed) are very low.

> don't you think it can be a major issue in practice if 100 user trying to push at the same time and last 1 will have to pull 99 time before being able to push.?

No, because if in that case, you would avoid that issue by allowing each user to push into a dedicated branch (one per user).
Such a concurrent operation would be resolved on the server side (with merges done in an integration branch). It would not be left to the clients side (where what you describe would be too cumbersome to resolve)

> what about using queuing system (rabbitmq probably) to transfer all git objects to a bare repo and setting the head as required. what is your thought on it. would it be nice in clustering situation?

You need to make sure the transfer won't fail (hence one branch per user)
Then, on that bare git repo, another process can try and merge any new commit pushed to a user branch. If it fails because of conflicts, it would send a notification email for an integrator to resolve the situation.

Comment: thanks for you view. but thats exactly the problem. N user running a thread which is continuously trying to push something. And obviously Only one user can push. So N-1 end up pulling again.

Comment: @runitfirst then you need to consider one branch per user, if you want your threads to always succeeds. Deals with merging those branches on the server side, instead of trying to make it work from the clients side.

Answer (score 2):

If your N users are machines, and all run at the same speed, then yes, you will have this problem.

Realistically, though, let's view the problem with just four actors, and see whether three of them really do have this issue.  Our four players are Carol, David, Emma, and Fallon.

The central repository starts with commits A and B, as in your example.  Somehow, all four of Carol, David, Emma, and Fallon finish their new commits all at the same time, and all push at 14:17:23.2, but Carol's computer is the fastest, so her commit makes it in to the central repository:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

David, Emma, and Fallon get an error message telling them that their pushes are not fast-forwards and they must retry.  But Fallon's phone is ringing (or buzzing with a text) so he gets distracted by that.  Meanwhile David and Emma both notice that their push has failed.

David has not seen this before, so he now has to go search StackOverflow to see what he's supposed to do.  Emma is more familiar with Git; she runs `git fetch && git rebase && git show` and sees that her change is good.  It is now 14:18:09.6.  Emma types in `git push origin master` and her push goes through:

```
A--B--C--E
```

David is now reading about merge vs rebase.  Fallon gets off the phone at 14:19:39, more or less, and notices the failure.  David and Fallon both run `git pull` (they're not as smart as Emma and don't realize that rebase is better); their repositories become:

```
A--B--C--E--M   <-- master
    \      /
     D----/
```

and:

```
A--B--C--E--G   <-- master
    \      /
     F----/
```

respectively.  By some miracle, they both push at almost the same time, 14:21:01-and-a-fraction, with Fallon being a bit ahead, so his push goes through and David gets another "non-fast-forward" error.  The central repository now mirror's Fallon's repository:

```
A--B--C--E--G   <-- master
    \      /
     F----/
```

David, of course, read about rebase as well, so he tries `git pull --rebase`, thinking it's somehow magically different from `git pull` (when all it really does is run the moral equivalent of `git fetch && git rebase` instead of `git fetch && git merge`).  This copies his commit `D` to the end of `G`:

```
A--B--C--E--G--D'   <-- master
   |\      /
   | F----/
   \
    D  [abandoned]
```

and he tries `git push` again and succeeds, at 14:21:28.  The central repository gets commit `D'` on `master` and everyone is happy.

David is the only one who has had to fetch twice, and the whole process has taken about four minutes.  Of course he still doesn't understand how `git pull` really works, but at least he now knows to use rebase. :-)

Comment: +1, but this process would not scale well. As I mentioned, for a large number of users, dedicated branches and server-side merges would be more sustainable.

Comment: Dedicated branches, at least, with mainline branches having alternative merge methods. In practice I have not seen problems even with a few dozen people using one branch.

Comment: nice explanation. as i commented there is no user only machines. Using gitpython and watchdog library to detect changes in file systems..commiting them and pushing them. Nothing is manual, all through continuously running threads

Comment: In that case, you definitely need a different approach.  Git's "devolve responsibility" approach is fine, but it's oriented towards Poisson or exponential distributions, and you've posited a situation with clustered distributions (distributing changes to N similar-or-identical machines that then try to apply their N changes simultaneously). Clearly it's more appropriate to source-control the items *before* distribution instead of after, reducing N to 1.

Comment: @VonC Agree. what about using queuing system(rabbitmq probably) to transfer all git objects to a bare repo and setting the head as required.  what is your thought on it.  would it be nice in clustering situation?. merge conflicts will be impossible to solve in that case i think...